# Laço de repetição funciona em um caso, mas não funciona em outro (JS)

Tags: javascript, loop, objetos

Não estou conseguindo entender o porquê de o laço abaixo funcionar para atribuir um novo valor ao índice, mas não funcionar para mudar a propriedade de um objeto. O que fiz de errado, galera?

```js
var p = ["teste1", "teste2", "teste3", "teste4"];

for (var key in p) {
    if (p.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        console.log(key + " -> " + p[key]); // AQUI O LAÇO FUNCIONA.
        var people = [
          {
            name: p[key],
            url: "http://example.com/johnsmith"
          }
        ];        
        console.log(people[key]); // AQUI O LAÇO NÃO FUNCIONA. =\
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quando você chama `people[key]`, tenta acessar uma posição especificada por `key`. No entanto, você está substituindo o conteúdo do seu vetor `people` a cada iteração sobre `p`, fazendo com que esse vetor tenha sempre apenas 1 item.

Eu suponho que você queira percorrer `p` e, para cada item, inserir um objeto em `people`, com o nome igual a `p[key]` e a url definida. Portanto, deve-se inicializar o vetor antes do laço `for` e adicionar o objeto [usando `push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push).

```js
var p = ["teste1", "teste2", "teste3", "teste4"];
var people = [];

for (var key in p) {
  if (p.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    console.log(`${key} -> ${p[key]}`);

    people.push({
      name: p[key],
      url: "http://example.com/johnsmith"
    })

    console.log(people[key]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Exatamente como você supôs, Lucas! Muito obrigado pela dica, meu caro!

Comment: Sem contar que eu não conhecia o método push()! :)

Comment: Que bom que pude ajudar! ;)