# Como colocar dois arrays dentro de um único laço de repetição para povoar um objeto?

Tags: javascript, array, for, objetos

Com base [nessa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35554108/javascript-html5-array-search-and-return-from-html5-text-box-if-in-array/35554687#35554687) e [nessa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/470722/la%C3%A7o-de-repeti%C3%A7%C3%A3o-funciona-em-um-caso-mas-n%C3%A3o-funciona-em-outro-js/470725#470725), estou criando uma caixa de pesquisa instantânea que me retorne resultados com base nos itens de dois arrays com elementos `p` e `a` de certas classes presentes na página.

A ideia é que o primeiro array (`p`) seja a propriedade `name`; e o array `a` seja a propriedade `url`. O código funciona muitíssimo bem, entretanto não sei bem como usar o valores do meu array `a` para povoar a propriedade `url` do meu objeto `people`, visto que a propriedade `name` funciona tranquilamente.

Em suma, como posso adicionar os itens do array `a` dentro do laço de repetição e setar seus valores na propriedade `url`?

```js
var p = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll("[class='h6']")).map(function(x){return x.innerHTML});
var a = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll("[class='link']")).map(function(y){return y.href});

var people = [];
for (var key in p) {
    if (p.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        people.push({
            name: p[key],
            url: "A ideia é que apareça a URL presente no parágrafo de nome 'Teste N'"
          })
        console.log(people[key])
    }
}
```

```html
<a class="link" href="url1.html"><p class="h6">Teste 1</p></a>
<a class="link" href="url2.html"><p class="h6">Teste 2</p></a>
<a class="link" href="url3.html"><p class="h6">Teste 3</p></a>
<a class="link" href="url4.html"><p class="h6">Teste 4</p></a>
<a class="link" href="url5.html"><p class="h6">Teste 5</p></a>
```

Comment: Importante você [edit] sua pergunta e explicar de maneira objetiva e pontual a dificuldade encontrada, acompanhada de um [mcve] do problema e tentativa de solução. Para aproveitar melhor o site, entender e evitar fechamentos e negativações vale a pena ler o [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045/70).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se a estrutura **sempre** é essa, com os parágrafos dentro das tags `a`, então você não precisa construir dois arrays para depois fazer um *loop* em ambos.

Basta buscar apenas pelas tags `p` e acessar o `a` através da propriedade [`parentNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/parentNode). E para buscar especificamente pelo nome da classe, pode usar [`getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) (não é que seja "melhor", é apenas para mostrar uma alternativa à `querySelectorAll`).

E para fazer o *loop* pelos elementos, não precisa criar um array com `slice`. Se não vai precisar deste array depois e só vai usá-lo no *loop*, basta usar [`for..of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of):

```js
let people = [];
for (const p of document.getElementsByClassName("h6")) {
    people.push({ name: p.innerHTML, url: p.parentNode.href });
}
console.log(people);
```

```html
<a class="link" href="url1.html"><p class="h6">Teste 1</p></a>
<a class="link" href="url2.html"><p class="h6">Teste 2</p></a>
<a class="link" href="url3.html"><p class="h6">Teste 3</p></a>
<a class="link" href="url4.html"><p class="h6">Teste 4</p></a>
<a class="link" href="url5.html"><p class="h6">Teste 5</p></a>
```

Esta solução funciona se cada `p` é filho imediato da tag `a`.

---

Ou, pode fazer o contrário: buscar pelas tags `a` e a partir delas buscar pelo parágrafo:

```js
let people = [];
for (const a of document.getElementsByClassName("link")) {
    // busca pelo parágrafo a partir da tag "a"
    let p = a.querySelector('p[class="h6"]');
    people.push({ name: p.innerHTML, url: a.href });
}
console.log(people);
```

```html
<a class="link" href="url1.html"><p class="h6">Teste 1</p></a>
<a class="link" href="url2.html"><p class="h6">Teste 2</p></a>
<a class="link" href="url3.html"><p class="h6">Teste 3</p></a>
<a class="link" href="url4.html"><p class="h6">Teste 4</p></a>
<a class="link" href="url5.html"><p class="h6">Teste 5</p></a>
```

Repare que `a.querySelector('p[class="h6"]')` faz a busca a partir da tag `a` (e não do `document`), assim eu garanto que só vou buscar pela tag `p` cuja classe é "h6" que está dentro desta tag.

Esta solução é mais geral porque o `p` não precisa ser necessariamente filho imediato de `a`: ele pode estar em qualquer nível abaixo. Ex:

```js
let people = [];
for (const a of document.getElementsByClassName("link")) {
    // busca pelo parágrafo a partir da tag "a"
    let p = a.querySelector('p[class="h6"]');
    people.push({ name: p.innerHTML, url: a.href });
}
console.log(people);
```

```html
<a class="link" href="url1.html">
  <div>bla
    <div>bla
      <p class="h6">Teste 1</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</a>
```

---

### Se quiser mesmo usar os arrays

Eu já disse nos comentários que não precisaria criar os arrays, mas se a ideia é usá-los, há algumas considerações a se fazer.

[Segundo a documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in#Array_iteration_and_for...in), o uso de `for..in` **não** é recomendado para percorrer arrays. Isso porque o `for..in` não garante a ordem dos elementos, além de outros problemas citados [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/q/500504).

Claro que alguns browsers *podem* retornar os elementos na ordem, mas isso não é garantido (e mesmo assim, vale se atentar para o [link já citado](https://stackoverflow.com/q/500504)). Obviamente que se a ordem não é importante e os problemas do link já citado não acontecem, não haveria problema em usar `for..in`. Mas se quiser garantir a ordem, uma alternativa é iterar pelos índices dos arrays diretamente, usando o `for` "tradicional".

No código abaixo também mostro 2 maneiras diferentes de obter os arrays: com [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) e com [*spread syntax*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) (não acho que são melhores nem piores que [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice), é apenas para mostrar outras formas de fazer).

```js
// alternativas à slice
var p = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("[class='h6']")).map(function(x) { return x.innerHTML });
var a = [...document.querySelectorAll("[class='link']")].map(function(y) { return y.href });

let people = [];
let tamanho = Math.min(a.length, p.length); // pega o tamanho do menor array
for (let i = 0; i < tamanho; i++) {
    people.push({ name: p[i], url: a[i] });
}
console.log(people);
```

```html
<a class="link" href="url1.html"><p class="h6">Teste 1</p></a>
<a class="link" href="url2.html"><p class="h6">Teste 2</p></a>
<a class="link" href="url3.html"><p class="h6">Teste 3</p></a>
<a class="link" href="url4.html"><p class="h6">Teste 4</p></a>
<a class="link" href="url5.html"><p class="h6">Teste 5</p></a>
```

Também fiz um tratamento para o caso dos arrays terem tamanhos diferentes, e nesse caso o `for` só vai até o menor dos arrays terminar. Assim você não precisa usar `hasOwnProperty`, pois estou acessando índices que com certeza existem em ambos (e são somente os índices numéricos, não há o risco de trazer outras propriedades, como pode ocorrer com `for..in`).

Claro que no seu caso eles têm tamanhos iguais, pois a estrutura do HTML garante isso (cada `a` tem o seu respectivo `p`) - mas se a estrutura já garante isso, volto a insistir que os arrays não seriam necessários e as soluções propostas acima são mais simples e diretas (a menos, é claro, que você precise usar os arrays para fazer outras coisas depois, aí faria sentido criá-los).

Comment: Embora seja uma boa prática o que você descreveu, não responde a pergunta. A pergunta tão somente questiona como preencher um vetor de objetos, onde cada objeto é construído utilizando valores de dois vetores diferentes.

Comment: @LucasSamuel Desculpe, mas meu entendimento foi outro. Ele quer preencher o objeto com o texto dos parágrafos e os respectivos links. **A forma que ele tentou resolver** foi construindo 2 arrays e tentando percorrê-los ao mesmo tempo, mas eu não acho que é a melhor solução, por isso eu disse que isso não era necessário e sugeri outra forma. Ou seja, é o típico caso do [Problema XY](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/499/112052)

Comment: @LucasSamuel Se a estrutura do HTML fosse outra, com os parágrafos e links sem nenhuma relação entre si, aí sim eu concordo que o único jeito seria construir os 2 arrays e percorrê-los ao mesmo tempo. Mas como ele deu um exemplo do HTML, eu sugeri uma solução que acho melhor. Enfim, eu prefiro sempre dar uma solução que acredito ser melhor em vez de insistir em uma que acho pior

Comment: @LucasSamuel e hkotsubo, muito obrigado pelos comentários! Todas as ponderações de vocês me ajudaram bastante! Valeu mesmo aos dois!

Comment: Hkotsubo, vou aceitar a resposta do @LucasSamuel porque a resposta dele tem mais relação com o que eu perguntei originalmente. Entretanto, o que você escreveu me abriu muito os olhos! De fato, eu causei um problema XY, e você me sugeriu uma forma mais simples de resolver meu problema com uma solução muito boa! A partir de agora, vou procurar fazer perguntas mais claras aqui no SO. Muito obrigado pela resposta também, cara! Valeu!

Comment: @winiercape Se vc reconhece que a pergunta é XY, bastava editá-la. Algo como: "preciso fazer X, tentei com Y mas o resultado foi A, só que deveria ser B. Dá pra fazer com Y ou tem outro jeito?" - assim foca mais no X e não no Y. De qualquer forma, eu ainda prefiro não criar os 2 arrays, me parece uma volta muito grande para o que vc quer fazer - a menos, é claro, que vc precise dos elementos para fazer outras coisas depois, aí valeria a pena ter os arrays

Comment: @winiercape Atualizei a resposta com alguns detalhes sobre o uso de `for..in` e uma alternativa para unir os 2 arrays, espero que ajude

Comment: Obrigado, hkotsubo! A discussão aqui ficou interessante, e foi bem proveitoso para mim ler as considerações de ambos. Alterei a resposta, meu caro. Mais uma vez obrigado!

Answer (score 2):

Como cada elemento `a` contém um `href` e dentro de cada `a` existe um `p`, podemos assumir que a variável `key`, utilizada na posição de `p` no laço `for`, também pode ser usada para definir a posição de `a`. E isso é verdade porque, se existe `a`, dentro dele existe um `p` determinado.

Pode ter ficado meio confuso, mas, você consegue usar a variável `key` no laço `for` tanto para acessar uma posição em `p` quanto em `a`. Isso é possível porque `key` inicia em 0 e vai até o número total de elementos em `p`, que é o mesmo número de elementos em `a`.

```js
var p = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll("[class='h6']")).map(function(x){return x.innerHTML});
var a = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll("[class='link']")).map(function(y){return y.href});

var people = [];
for (var key in p) {
    if (p.hasOwnProperty(key) && a.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        people.push({
            name: p[key],
            url: a[key]
          })
        console.log(people[key])
    }
}
```

```html
<a class="link" href="url1.html"><p class="h6">Teste 1</p></a>
<a class="link" href="url2.html"><p class="h6">Teste 2</p></a>
<a class="link" href="url3.html"><p class="h6">Teste 3</p></a>
<a class="link" href="url4.html"><p class="h6">Teste 4</p></a>
<a class="link" href="url5.html"><p class="h6">Teste 5</p></a>
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, Lucas! A resposta do @hkotsubo é muito prática mesmo, e pensando no problema específico de unir dois arrays, tua resposta cabe muito bem como a solução para a pergunta-título do post. Valeu! Alterei a resposta para a do hkotsubo por ele responder com outras ideias que, além de unir os dois arrays (minha dúvida inicial), solucionam meu problema inicial de forma mais simples em comparação com a que eu havia imaginado a princípio. Mas obrigado mesmo assim, cara! Valeu mesmo!